# How to push another page in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I am working with one project on Xcode with SnapKit and without storyboard.
I didn't touch AppDelegate.
I have this code on SceneDelegate.

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
    }
}
```

Project's hierarchy like that:

- HomePage(Group)

1. TabBarController
2. ViewController
3. HomeCollectionViewCell

- ShopPage(Group)
  ...
- MessagePage(Group)
  ...
- ProfilePage(Group)

1. ProfileViewController
2. SettingsViewController

I want to open SettingsViewController when settingsButton(on ProfileViewController) tapped.

This is my code in the TabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupTabs()
        selectedIndex = 3
        tabBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 155/255, blue: 247/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Tab Setup
    private func setupTabs(){
        let home = self.createNav(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house"), vc: ViewController())
        let shop = self.createNav(title: "Shop", image: UIImage(systemName: "bag"), vc: ShopViewController())
        let message = self.createNav(title: "Message", image: UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis.message"), vc: MessageViewController())
        let profile = self.createNav(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), vc: ProfileViewController())
        self.setViewControllers([home, shop, message, profile], animated: true)
    }
    
    private func createNav(title: String, image: UIImage?, vc: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController{
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.tabBarItem.title = title
        nav.tabBarItem.image = image
        return nav
    }
}
```

This is my code in the ProfileViewController:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var settingButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gearshape"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 250/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    @objc private func openSettings() {
        let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

private extension ProfileViewController {
    func setupUI() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(settingButton)
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        settingButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tap settingButton nothing happens.

I tried to set rootViewController like that on Scene Delegate:
`window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())`

Also I tried here set ProfileViewController as a rootViewController

Also I tried with present method:

```
@objc private func openSettings() {
    let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
    present(settingsViewController, animated: true)
}
```

---

**Edit**

Sorry, I thought that this part of code is not related to my problem and didn't provide you with this. My code was like that:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var topView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var topTitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Profile"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 19)
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var settingButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gearshape"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    @objc private func openSettings() {
        print("button")
        let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: true)
    }


}

// MARK: - setting iui methods
private extension ProfileViewController {
    func setupUI() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(topView)
        topView.addSubview(topTitle)
        topView.addSubview(settingButton)
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        topView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.08)
        }
        
        topTitle.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        settingButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
            make.height.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.4)
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.15)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But it turns out the problem was in the topview, but I don’t know exactly why. If my button is in the topview it is not pressed, but if outside then everything works fine.

Comment: You don't have a navigation controller to push your settings view controller on, so the `navigation controller?.push` won't do anything as 'navigationcontroller` is nil. If you want to use a navigation controller then you need to allocate one, set its root view controller to profile view controller and add the navigation controller to your tab bar controller in place of the profile controller.  When using a tab bar controller you typically want each tab to have its own navigation controller with its root set to the relevant view controller for that tab.

Comment: The modal `present` should have worked.

Comment: @Paulw11, actually the OP's code in their tab bar controller's `setupTabs()` function calls a function `createNav()` embeds each tab's view controller in a navigation controller.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I missed that.  In which case since neither the `push` nor the `present` is working, there is a problem somewhere else; possibly in `SettingsViewController`. More information is needed.

Comment: *"when I tap settingButton nothing happens"* ... is `func openSettings()` being called? Add a `print` statement or a breakpoint to confirm that. Quick test using the code you posted -- no problem. Tapping the "gear" button pushes to `SettingsViewController`

Comment: I found where I was wrong :)
On ProfileViewController I have topView which has a title on the center and this settingButton on the left side. So when settingButton in the topView it is not working, but I tried to add it into just "view" it is working. 

I have another question, how I can add settingButton in the topView correctly?

Comment: @DonMag can you help with that please!

Comment: @Yernur - you haven't shown us anything related to `topView` ...

Comment: @Yernur - use `topView.backgroundColor = .yellow` so you can see its frame and confirm that the `settingButton` is actually contained in `topView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your tabs holds a `UINavigationController` ...

So, your "Profile" tab has a `UINavigationController` with a root view controller of `ProfileViewController` ...

You then add your `topView` as a subview of `ProfileViewController`'s view, and you constrain it to the top of that ***view*** -- ignoring the safe-area, which includes the navigation bar.

If I modify your code to add some background colors:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    
    topView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

You cannot tap a button (or any other UI element) that is covered by the navigation bar.

If you want a "Title" and a right-side button on that navigation bar, manage that with the navigation bar...

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // don't call anything in your current setupUI() func
        //setupUI()
        
        self.title = "Profile"
        let b = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "gearshape"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openSettings))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = b
    }
    
    @objc private func openSettings() {
        print("button")
        let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

and tapping the Gear button **will** call `openSettings()`